# Retry on deadlock for MySQL / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, database-deadlocks

I have searched for quite some time now and can't found a solution to my problem. We are using SQLAlchemy in conjunction with MySQL for our project and we encounter several time the dreaded error:

> 1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'.

We would like to try to restart the transaction at most three times in this case.

I have started to write a decorator that does this but i don't know how to save the session state before the fail and retry the same transaction after it ? (As SQLAlchemy requires a rollback whenever an exception is raised)

My work so far,

```
def retry_on_deadlock_decorator(func):
    lock_messages_error = ['Deadlock found', 'Lock wait timeout exceeded']

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        attempt_count = 0
        while attempt_count < settings.MAXIMUM_RETRY_ON_DEADLOCK:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except OperationalError as e:
                if any(msg in e.message for msg in lock_messages_error) \
                        and attempt_count <= settings.MAXIMUM_RETRY_ON_DEADLOCK:
                    logger.error('Deadlock detected. Trying sql transaction once more. Attempts count: %s'
                                 % (attempt_count + 1))
                else:
                    raise
            attempt_count += 1
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Did I help you? Or you found another solution. Please share any result.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do that with the `Session` from the outside. `Session` would have to support this internally. It would involve saving a lot of private state, so this may not be worth your time.

I completely ditched most ORM stuff in favour of the lower level SQLAlchemy Core interface. Using that (or even any dbapi interface) you can trivially use your `retry_on_deadlock_decorator` decorator (see question above) to make a retry-aware `db.execute` wrapper.

```
 @retry_on_deadlock_decorator
 def deadlock_safe_execute(db, stmt, *args, **kw):
     return db.execute(stmt, *args, **kw)
```

And instead of

```
 db.execute("UPDATE users SET active=0")
```

you do

```
 deadlock_safe_execute(db, "UPDATE users SET active=0")
```

which will retry automatically if a deadlock happens.

Comment: pi, what happens if your retry fails in another deadlock?  Is two attempts really enough or should there be some kind of exponential back off?

Comment: Judging from experience 2 or 3 times should be enough. Depends heavily on your workload though. 3 times is good enough to reduce the noise in the error log dramatically. I didn't see the need for exponential back off in my code, but because it is complexity I would only add it if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use code like this?

```
try: 

     Perform table transaction 
     break 
except: 
     rollback 
     delay 
     try again to perform table transaction
```

> The only way to truly handle deadlocks is to write your code to expect
>   them. This generally isn't very difficult if your database code is
>   well written. Often you can just put a try/catch around the query
>   execution logic and look for a deadlock when errors occur. If you
>   catch one, the normal thing to do is just attempt to execute the
>   failed query again.

Usefull links:

- [How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)
- [Understanding Autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit)
- [Property MySQLConnection.autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html)